# UIView: Force viewDidLoad / A way to release an UIView?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

Some important part of my code is running in viewDidLoad and I was wondering is there was a way to unload an UIView so that when my controller calls it again it must go through viewDidLoad again?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should perhaps rethink the positioning of that code if its important.

If you need it to run each time the view is displayed, consider placing it in `view[Will/Did]Appear`.

Answer (score 4):

Put those important part of code into `-viewWillAppear:`. `-viewDidLoad` is meant for initialization *only*.

---

You can also manually call `-viewDidLoad` or set the `view` property to `nil`.

Comment: @Tom: `viewWillAppear:` will be called when the view controller *appears*. How often do you want it to be called?

Comment: For some reason my viewWillAppear only gets called once. Is there a way to unload a view?